# How to see my site's problems with Google?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, googlebot, search-results

I recently made a website, which aims for a certain search query.

It was like 5th or 6th for a few days. But now it's not even in the first 3 pages.
There are no warnings in Webmaster Tools. There is nothing different than other -seo-wise successful- sites that I did. I do not use any "black-hat" techniques.

I just cannot see what the problem is.

### Clues:

1. It is not sandboxed, because the results appear when I search for `site:mysite.tk`
2. It was actually another URL, *samething*.netii.net, then I 301-redirected it to *samething*.tk. Can it be a problem ?
3. I am using a free web host (000webhost). But again, a lot of other sites I do already uses 000webhost. So loading time is not so crucial I guess.
4. There are a lot of auto-generated pages, like the list of departments and courses etc. But the sitemap only has 59 department links.
5. It has no backlinks yet. But it should still rank high, based on my previous experience.

What could be the problem that Google not ranks my site even in the first pages ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's your problem!

Your site is new and will take as much as 60 days under normal circumstances to settle out. Also you have no backlinks which indicates popularity and quality. In addition, you are using a free host which is also evaluated to indicate quality. I assume that your SEO work is not up to par as well. Search engines do not generally like auto-generated pages with the exception of e-commerce and some other considerations. I assume you do not have any hand edited content which search engines use to evaluate site quality and authority. Your redirect should not be a problem, but does add confusion for a while which can be 6 months or more depending upon how fast the search engines spider your new and old site. Your sitemap should not be a problem except that is not complete and may not be helping you as much as you desire.

The bounce you saw is typical velocity for any new site. It does not take search engines long to collect enough metrics to begin to properly place your site. Your drop is likely downward velocity that will settle out in time.

The single most important thing you can do is to find a quality web host. Free hosts are seen as bad neighborhoods where low quality sites come from. Also do appropriate SEO work for your site. Focus on keywords other than your branding keywords which should also be important.

In the end, you will be okay. Creating a new site even done extremely well takes generally 60 days to settle into the SERPs. It can take as much as a year. Which leads me to the second most important thing you can do. Create quality backlinks.